# What does this SQL Server icon mean?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

What does the icon of a server with a blue database symbol mean?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe (and someone should hopefully correct me if I'm wrong) that you're connected to an Azure SQL DB hosted on Azure, rather than a SQL Server database [as shown here](http://ppe.blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/02/15/managing-federations-in-sql-azure-with-the-sql-server-management-studio-of-sql-server-2012-rc0-new.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

It's definitely SQL Azure. You can easily recognize it as the icon is azure, unlike the green one for a regular SQL Server instance

You can see the the video by Thomas LaRock here

[How To Connect to SQL Azure database using SSMS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmmBiBS_mKU)